# Is "looks up" a correct phrase when referring to a computer searching for information?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, computing

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> The computer looks up the email address provided.

Guess it's just my brain, but "looks up" didn't have a familiar ring to it when I read the sentence back. Although "look up" seems fine in computing, I'm not sure if the simple present form "looks up" works.

Comment: What do you mean by "appropriate"?

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ I've rewritten for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, but still not clear for me. Are you asking if the multi-word verb _look up_ can apply to computers as the subject? Or are you asking if it requires a modal verb? Because AFAIK, any subject whose verb works with a modal can also function with simple tense. Is this about grammaticallity , or usage?

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ I've edited further. Also, you answered my question when you said, "any subject whose verb works with a modal can also function with simple tense." :)

Comment: Maybe you're asking if it's normal to animate the computer to look. Yes, it is.

Comment: @YosefBaskin yes! Thank you. :)

Comment: As a computer programmer for 40 years, I find it very idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually specifically related to computer science. One of the most common, LUTs.

> In computer science, a lookup table (LUT) is an array that replaces runtime computation with a simpler array indexing operation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table

Comment: Ah! I see I hadn't made it clear that I understand that the phrasal verb "look up" works fine in computing. I was only uncertain about the simple present form of it. I've edited my post.

Comment: @jmach The simple present tense is fine if (as is probably the case) the piece of writing is describing a process one of the stages of which is the validation or retrieval of the email address. The description of currently implemented processes is often witten entirely in the simple present tense and all the verbs used match that tense. It's the analagous to "The postman parks his van outside my house while he delivers the mail to the houses in my close.". This is routine behaviour: he did it yesterday, he did it today and will do it tomorrow so the present tense is appropriate.